# EndlessAdapter Try Again Button

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I am using EndlessAdapter for a while but I couldn't implement the try again button functionality on the pending view. In Play Store, when we load additional data and there is a network connection, the pending view becomes a textview with try again button.

I want to do this with EndlessAdapter from commonsware but I couln't because it hides the pending row when there is a exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I have never seen the behavior you cite from the Play Store. If there is no network connection, it doesn't show a list.

Your "try again" button would need to be part of a regular row, not in the pending view, for it to have a hope of working with `EndlessAdapter`. It may be that you will need to roll your own "endless" construct that can take into account your desire for this retry functionality.

Comment: When there is no internet connection at the beginning, you are correct, play store does not show the list. If the connection is closed after the list is shown and the user tries to scroll down, it shows the user a row with a refresh button beneath the list.

Comment: Endless adapter is really really basic. I have tried to make it like in the Google play app. I have asked 2 questions and in both of them you did not know it at all. Thank you for the lib BTW